# Index out of range with different lists

Tags: python, python-2.7

So when I run my program with anything other an "SKY"* it will work but when I run it with SKY it doesn't work.

```
import urllib
import re

newsymbolslist = ["NFLX", "GOOG", "VNR", "AAPL", "SKY"]

i=0
while i<len(newsymbolslist):
    url = ("http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/" +newsymbolslist[i]+ "/real-time")
    htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(url)
    htmltext = htmlfile.read()
    regex = '<span id="quotes_content_left_OverallStockRating1_lblPercentage" class="comm_bullrating">(.+?)</span>'
    pattern = re.compile(regex)
    price = re.findall(pattern,htmltext)

    print (newsymbolslist[i] + " is: " + price[0])

    i+=1
```

*Sky being the last symbol in the newsymbolslist list

Comment: Please indent the code to match how it appears in your editor. Also you should iterate over a list with `for item in listname:` if you don't need to access the index, which in this case you don't.

Comment: Its not, the browser messed up my indenting while pasting.

Comment: @AdamSmith, that's true, probably shouldn't just assume like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information extracted by the regex for SKY is corrupt, as can be seen from:

```
import urllib
import re

newsymbolslist = ["NFLX", "GOOG", "VNR", "AAPL", "SKY"]

i=0
while i<len(newsymbolslist):
    url = ("http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/" +newsymbolslist[i]+ "/real-time")
    htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(url)
    htmltext = htmlfile.read()
    regex = '<span id="quotes_content_left_OverallStockRating1_lblPercentage" class="comm_bullrating">(.+?)</span>'
    pattern = re.compile(regex)
    price = re.findall(pattern,htmltext)

    print (newsymbolslist[i] + " is: " + str (price))

    i+=1
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because nasdaq.com doesn't return a page containing a `<span id="quotes_content_left_OverallStockRating1_lblPercentage" class="comm_bullrating">` tag for SKY

Comment: But when I try the my program to read my list of stock symbols from nasdaq it still returns that error

Comment: Your code assumes that the page returned for `http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/<symbol>/real-time` always contains an element of the format mentioned in my reply. This is clearly not the case for SKY.

Answer (score 0):

A more pythonic way of looping over the list would be:

```
import urllib
import re

newsymbolslist = ["NFLX", "GOOG", "VNR", "AAPL", "SKY"]

for symbol in newsymbolslist:
    url = ("http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/" + symbol + "/real-time")
    htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(url)
    htmltext = htmlfile.read()
    regex = '<span id="quotes_content_left_OverallStockRating1_lblPercentage" class="comm_bullrating">(.+?)</span>'
    pattern = re.compile(regex)
    price = re.findall(pattern,htmltext)

    print (symbol + " is: " + price[0])
```

The problem with sky is that the class is `comm_50rating` rather than `comm_bullrating`